# How to cd into more than one directory?

Tags: bash

I'm not sure if I'm asking that right, but here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# foundation-setup.sh --- Gets the latest Zurb Foundation release
if test $1
then  
    mkdir $* 
    cd $* 
    wget -q http://foundation.zurb.com/cdn/releases/foundation-latest.zip
    unzip -q foundation-latest.zip
    rm foundation-latest.zip
else     
       echo 'Missing directory Argument!'
fi
```

When I run this with `./foundation-setup.sh a b c`, it works but it only unzips
to the first directory argument. I think it has something to do with the `cd $*`
. By the way I'm new to Linux and Bash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to extract the downloaded zip in each of the three directories the  middle part of the script should be:

```
mkdir -- "$@" || exit 
wget -q http://foundation.zurb.com/cdn/releases/foundation-latest.zip &&
  for d do
     (
       cd -- "$d" &&
         unzip -q ../foundation-latest.zip
     )
  done &&
  rm foundation-latest.zip
```